# Password strong - not require each condition

Tags: regex

I have password validation by regex.This is my expression:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

It works - the password must contain at least 1 digit, at least 1 lower case letter, at least 1 upper case letter and at least special character: `@#$%^&+=`.  So I have to input all this characters.

But I'd like password, which has at least 3 combination, not all 4.
So these passwords should be good:

`2Df` (not special character), `dF#` (not digit), `a4%` (not upper case).  I'd like to ask, how this regex expression should look? I could write each expression to check each combination, for example:

- Not include digit: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$`
- Not include upper case: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$`

But maybe I can do it in one expression.

Comment: Which language are you doing this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it with regular expressions, I'd suggest (for clarity's sake) to check all four conditions after one another. For readability, you could first try to find `\d` in your password, then `[a-z]`, then `[A-Z]` and then `[@#$%^&+=]` (although you might want to use `[\W_]` instead to allow more than just those few extra characters). Then check if at least three of these worked.

If you *have* to do it in a single regex, you could use alternation:

```
^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])|(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*\d)).*$
```

but that is just ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Why did you use regular expression for that? Simply iterate over your password string and count number of desired character types. In PHP you can use function like `count_chars()`.

Pseudo code for that:

```
      foreach(password as char) {
        if (is_digit(char))
           digits++;
        if (is_specialchar(char))
           special++;
        if (is_lower(char))
           lower++;
        if (is_upper(char))
           upper++;
        //etc
      }
```

Now you can define any requirements you wish

```
      if (dgits > 0) and (lower > 0) and (special > 0)
         passowrd_ok()
      else
         password_bad()
```

in your case you can smartly count

```
     if (lower > 0)
        diversity++;
     if (upper > 0)
        diversity++;
     if (special > 0)
        diversity++;
     if (digit > 0)
        diversity++;

     if (diversity >= 3)   //at least 3 different types of characters in password
        pass_ok()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to validate password on ASP (not .NET) site - so I think, the best solution is regular expression.

Comment: @luk4443: why the hell? You can iterate over a string in VB, C# or whatever. In VB the loop is `For i = 0 To s.Length - 1` and access to each character is possible by `s.Chars(i)` or `Mid(s, i, 1)`

Comment: @luk443: Also take a look here, there's a question related to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80427/iterate-over-and-check-the-byte-value-of-every-character-in-a-string-vba