# Javascript regular expression with a condition

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password validation regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex)

I need to do the password validation in javascript with the below policies. Will you please let me know the regular expression for this? I'm quite new to regular expressions.

- Password should be 8 to 18 character long, and
  Password should meet at least 3 of the following conditions:
- Password should have at least one lower case character(a-z)
- Password should have at least one upper case character(a-z)
- Password should have at least one numeric value(0-9)
- Password should have a special character (i.e. @ . - _ # $ %)

Please help me out with this. I'm not able to determine how to provide a condition to meet this requirement.

Comment: Have you tried anything and run into specific problems? Why do you need a single regex for this?

Comment: why don't you just check each of those one at a time. should be simple enough.

Comment: This is asked very often here, and it's nearly a duplicate of [Password validation regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex) and [Password strong - not require each condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798062/password-strong-not-require-each-condition). These two answers also show that a single regex is not really suitable for this.

Comment: Requirement "Password should meet at least 3 of the following conditions" makes it impossible to use only one regexp to check.
Use 4 regexps with counter "how many fails", if counter > 2 then 'wrong password'

Comment: Thanks for the responses. After going through few threads, i understood as to why it can't be done with a single regexp. So i used 4 regexps to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is just to show how unreadable it is to do in one regular expression. Please consider other cleaner alternatives to write your code.**

It can be done in 1 regular expression, but it is horrible:

```
^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\x00-\x1f])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\x00-\x1f])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\x00-\x1f])).{8,18}$
```

It can be shorten a bit, but still as ugly:

```
^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\x00-\x1f])(?:(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z]))|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?:(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\x00-\x1f]))).{8,18}$
```

There are 4 extra conditions as you have mentioned in the question, which corresponds to these fragments:

- `(?=.*\d)`: Look-ahead for a digit (0-9)
- `(?=.*[a-z])`: Look-ahead for a lower case English alphabet (a-z)
- `(?=.*[A-Z])`: Look-ahead for an upper case English alphabet (A-Z)
- `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\x00-\x1f])`: Look-ahead for some character other than digits and English alphabet. Control characters are also excluded.

*To the best of my knowledge*, there is no mechanism in regular expression to say match 3 out of 4 conditions. So I have to enumerate all those conditions, which takes up the bulk of the regex.

`.{8,18}` just match 8-18 of any character. And the whole regex is anchored with `^` and `$`.